# How to view predicted values from MultiStep tensor flow model?

Tags: python, time-series, linear-regression, tensorflow2.0, prediction

I used timeseries dataframe with 9 variables, trying to predict 1 of them. I followed the official tutorial and got the final model. But I don't know how to view the predicted values.

```html
#Split the data
column_indices = {name: i for i, name in enumerate(df.columns)}
n = len(df)
train_data = df[0:int(n*0.7)]
val_data = df[int(n*0.7):int(n*0.9)]
test_data = df[int(n*0.9):]
num_features = df.shape[1]

#Data windowing....

#Split the data

#Train the model

class MultiStepLastBaseline(tf.keras.Model):
  def call(self, inputs):
    return tf.tile(inputs[:, -1:, :], [1, OUT_STEPS, 1])

last_baseline = MultiStepLastBaseline()
last_baseline.compile(loss=tf.losses.MeanSquaredError(),
                      metrics=[tf.metrics.MeanAbsoluteError()])

multi_val_performance = {}
multi_performance = {}

multi_val_performance['Last'] = last_baseline.evaluate(multi_window.val)
multi_performance['Last'] = last_baseline.evaluate(multi_window.test, verbose=0)
multi_window.plot(last_baseline)
```

Finally I got this plot
[model output plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HPOTq.png)

Now how can I see the predicted values for next two days? I tired the following but it says missing positional argument x

```html
MultiStepLastBaseline.predict(test_data)
```

Comment: Did you get the answer Prajwal? I even don't able to show the predicted values. Can you please help. I will be thankful to you

Comment: Basically u have to save the model first (that way the trained model weights are saved) then u can put the current data (that u want to use to predict) in the format that u used to train, then load the saved model and run it with your current data to view the prediction